# Paypal standard :How to handle Shipping and handlin?

Tags: php, paypal, shopping-cart

Is there any shipping variable for handling carts shipping charge
for paypal standard cart check out [cmd = "_cart"]? eg: for  each checkout I am having $10 shipping charge (independent of  number of items in cart  and cart amount) .
Is there any way to handle this ?
I found only shipping_x variables where i dont have individual shipping for all items,but for some items  i have .

Total shipping will be individual shipping charges of products -if any + common shipping $10

For now I added all shipping charges together and passing only shipping_1  to paypal .

Is there any better way ? Please suggest .

Thanks in advance  ,

Vinitha.

Comment: i prefer to do the shipping calculation locally then pass paypal the total

Comment: Vinitha can you tell me you are using do-direct method of paypal payment getway ?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass total amount like this :-

```
     $totalamount=($ordSubTotal+$shippingVal+$totalTax-$couponDiscount);  

    $nvpstr="&PAYMENTACTION=$paymentType&AMT=$amount&CREDITCARDTYPE=$creditCardType&ACCT=$creditCardNumber&EXPDATE=".$padDateMonth.$expDateYear."&CVV2=$cvv2Number&FIRSTNAME=$firstName&LASTNAME=$lastName&STREET=$address1&CITY=$city&STATE=$state".
        "&ZIP=$zip&COUNTRYCODE=AU&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyCode";
```

And Pass this value in :-

```
$resArray=hash_call("doDirectPayment",$nvpstr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply .but am using  [cmd = "_cart"]?3rd party cart checkout using paypal standard not paypal pro

Comment: You can use handling_x